Halachic inheritance
Is it possible that one holds differently then his community (i.e. Ashkenazim, Sfardim)? For example, Chuppah (Canopy).the shulchun Aruch says Chuppah is Yichud fit for cohabiting (rauy Libiah).and the Roma holds Canopy And Yichud which does not require it to be fit for cohabiting... see shulchan aruch Even Haezer 55 (I beleive) for the rundown exactly their Shitos.
The Ashkinazim go like the Roma. So my Question is:

it possible that a specific ashkenazi family holds like the shulchun aruch, or they can not hold like the shulchan aruch because he's an ashkenazi and ashkenazim hold like the roma? If yes, Whats the reason?
And if it can be that a ashkenazi can holds like the Roma would it be passed down to his kids as well?
if there is a possibility that he can do like the shulchun aruch (and/or his kids, if it transfers to them) this specific ashkenazi who holds like the shulchun aruch would doing like the Roma be valid because afterall he is an ashkenazi?

Thank you!

It took me a moment to realize when you typed Roma you meant Rema (רמ״א)

thank you for letting me know that ill try to fix that up soon
